# How to call a webservice using BizTalk 2013 R2 dynamic port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-orchestrations

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to do it correct.

I have an BizTalk 2013 R2 project with an orchestration. The orchestration has an receive port (AnyType schema) and dynamic send port (AnyType schema).
When a receive a soap message I do this in the "ConstructMessage" with an MessageAssigment shape:

```
Message_1 = opeTestPerson;
Message_1(*) = opeTestPerson(*);
Message_1(SOAP.AuthenticationScheme)="Anonymous";  
Message_1(SOAP.MethodName)="opeTestPerson";  
Message_1(BTS.SOAPAction)="http://XXXX.dk/TestPerson/opeTestPersonIn";  

Message_1(BTS.OutboundTransportType)="SOAP";  

CallOpeHentPersionPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = @"http://XXXX.dk/serTestPerson.asmx";
```

But when BizTalk try to call the webservice URL I get this error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

The strange ting is that the Web-server does not log any errors.

So can anyone tell how to call a web-service using dynamic port and send the SOAP header?

PS. I don't use a proxy call for calling, just direct call, because I need to call different URL depending on the incoming message.

Comment: Do you see any entries in the webservice log at all?  Have you verified you can connect from the BizTalk server to the web service using another tool.  e.g. Browser.   What BizTalk version are you using?  You have tagged it with two different ones and have named a third in the title.

Comment: Hi, Yes I see an entrie in the webservice log and connection is fine.. I'm getting an HTTP status 500 0 0 62 or 500 0 0 42, but the stange ting is that the server doesn't log any errors in the eventview, so I can't see why I'm getting an internal error..